# why program stop with big files

Tags: c, fork, execve

I'm trying to understand what's going on during the execution of this code:

I've this function to fork a process that execute a command

```
void    ft_fork(t_shell *shell, t_cmd *tmp_cmd)
{
    pid_t   cmd;
    int     status;

    status = 0;
    cmd = fork();
    if (cmd < 0)
        ft_clean(shell, 1);
    if (cmd == 0)
    {
        ft_execute_cmd(shell, tmp_cmd);
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    waitpid(cmd, &status, 0);
    if (!WTERMSIG(status))
        g_status = status >> 8;
}
```

and the ft_execute_cmd

```
void    ft_execute_cmd(t_shell *shell, t_cmd *tmp_cmd)
{
    char    *binpath;

    binpath = ft_search_cmd(shell, tmp_cmd);
    if (binpath)
    {
        if (execve(binpath, tmp_cmd->sim_cmd, shell->env) < 0)
        {
            ft_print_error(5);
            exit(127);
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to execute cat ./small_size_file | grep oi the program do what I expect, but when I try to execute cat .big_size_file | grep oi the parent stop and keep waiting for the child. this is the structure of the file descriptors before the fork

```
 ls -l /proc/17912/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 joao joao 64 dez  4 18:30 0 -> /dev/pts/4
l-wx------ 1 joao joao 64 dez  4 18:34 1 -> 'pipe:[47741]'
lrwx------ 1 joao joao 64 dez  4 18:34 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 joao joao 64 dez  4 18:34 3 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 joao joao 64 dez  4 18:34 4 -> /dev/pts/4
lr-x------ 1 joao joao 64 dez  4 18:34 5 -> 'pipe:[47741]'
```

can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried with small files and the program executes the cat as I expected but freezes with big ones.

Comment: Define "big". Have you found the boundary?

Comment: Perhaps the child process is blocked, waiting for more buffer-space to become available in stdout's buffer?  (but nothing ever reads from the other end of that stream, so child process is blocked forever, and since the parent process is waiting for the child process to exit, the parent process ends up blocked forever as well)

Comment: You're waiting before you've executed all the processes in the pipeline.  The `ft_fork()` function should not contain `wait()` or `waitpid()`.  If the file is bigger than the maximum pipe size (usually 64 KiB these days; once upon an æon ago, it was usually 5 KiB), the `cat` is blocked waiting for something to read from the pipe.  With a small file, the pipe can hold the data.  You will need to do some re-engineering — most likely by having `ft_fork()` return the PID of the child process, so that you can wait for it later.

Comment: How do you create a pipe? How, when and where do you call `ft_fork`? Are you calling it for each command in the pipeline? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Thank you all, tadman big is a 171KB and a small one a 18 bytes file, @Jeremy Friesner if you're right what should I do to unblock the process? the STDOUT could be the STDIN for the next process(like in this case), Jonathan Leffler but I would like to understand before I manage to solve this problem why the process frezes, maybe you have a point but if I redirect the STDIN to the original STADIN will solve the problem? (the cat will not wait becuase there's nothing to read). Some programmer dude I create the pipe only when I need to communicate between the two processes.

Comment: in gdb when I do ctrl + Z the execution continues with this error Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).
0x00007ffff7cea3ea in __GI___wait4 (pid=105450, stat_loc=0x7fffffffdd00, options=0, usage=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wait4.c:30
30 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wait4.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler your answer could be the right one. I moved the waitpid to the beginning and the block disappear.

Comment: A comment is not an answer, assume it was a hint how to proceed. ;-) You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it is not a forum. You are free to post an own answer, and to mark it (later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77603551/why-program-stop-with-big-files?noredirect=1#comment136811078_77603551) into an answer.*</sup>

You're waiting before you've executed all the processes in the pipeline — which is incorrect.  The processes in a pipeline must all execute concurrently to avoid any of the processes being blocked.

The `ft_fork()` function should not contain `wait()` or `waitpid()`. If the file is bigger than the maximum pipe size (usually 64 KiB these days; once upon an æon ago, it was usually 5 KiB), the `cat` command is blocked waiting for something to read from the pipe, but nothing will read from the pipe until the `cat` command completes — deadlock.  With a small file, the pipe can hold the data.

You will need to re-engineer the code — most likely by having `ft_fork()` return the PID of the child process so that you can wait for it after launching all the processes in the pipeline.

I note that since you've not provided an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) — the same idea by a different name), we cannot easily show working code for you.